# Auto Sorting after inputting data using UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I've made a UserForm to input data to specific columns on a worksheet("Endorse"), and it works fine.

After that, I have used a code to automatically sort the sheet based on the the values on Column A, B and C. But the sheet does not sort based on the criteria:

1. Column A: oldest to recent (date)
2. Column B: ascending order by: "BSUH (September),Frimley (October),CWH (November),Kingston (December)"
3. Column C: ascending order by: Allen,Christine,Feri,Hubert,Paula"

here is the code that i have used for the sheet("Endorse"):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    LastRow = Range("L4000").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Endorsed Candidates").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Endorsed Candidates").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("A2:A" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Endorsed Candidates").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("B2:B" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder _
        :="BSUH (September),Frimley (October),CWH (November),Kingston (December)", _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Endorsed Candidates").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("C2:C4000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder _
        :="Allen,Christine,Feri,Hubert,Paula", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Endorsed Candidates").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:L" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is the sheet after using the UserForm:
[enter image description here][1]

*ps I can't post an image yet in my question, hope you guys understand. And many thanks to those who could help!

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Perhaps you could crop the screenshot image so that I (or someone) can display it in your question?  Also, more information about what you have and what you're trying to do would be helpful.You haven't said what's wrong.Are you getting an error?  Also, check out "[ask]" as well as **how to create a [mcve]**.  This site gets about 6,000 questions a day -- the secret to getting the best expert assistance here is to 1. show that you've made an honest effort to solve the problem on your own, and then 2. make it as easy as possible for others to help you.  Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the phonetic Chinese sort order?

Comment: Hello mate, @AcsErno. I have just started to do coding. Would it be better to use a different sort order? What could you suggest? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many samples on Excel sorting on the net includes this `.SortMethod = xlPinYin` which applies to Chinese. I don't speak Chinese and I didn't test the effect of sorting a European text in Chinese order but I guess this may be confusing. Or at least redundant. So what if you simply remove it and see what happens?